# cannot set default INT value to 1 in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin will not allow me to add a new field to my database -- the new field is:

```
Field: itemCount
Type:  INT
Length: 5
Default: 'As Defined:'  1
AUTO_INCREMENT: yes
```

The error I get from phpMyAdmin is:

```
Error

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `useritems` CHANGE `itemCount` `itemCount` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' AUTO_INCREMENT

MySQL said: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'itemCount'
```

(note: the single quotes around the '1' in the error message are not mine -- I simply type 1
into phpMyAdmin for the new field.)

I don't get why I can create an INT, 'auto-increment' field but phpMyAdmin says "you can't set an INT to a default value of 1"

I tried setting it to zero, same error.
I tried making this the primary key field; and I tried it without making the field the primary key.  Same error.

How do I get phpMyAdmin to allow me to create an INT field that is auto-increment with a default value of 1 or zero?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to put a default value for auto-increment field. Do you mean to set a initial value for increments?

Comment: @husbas -- I need to set the initial value for increments to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, for any auto-increment column, the counting starts from 1. If you want to set it to anything higher than that, you may use following Alter query:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

Comment: Understood -- I looked in the docs and didn't see it mentioned but I'm sure it's in there (somewhere?).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html search for `AUTO_INCREMENT`